# Radio button inside tabpanel appears at the bottom

Tags: r, shiny

I am having a problem adding a radio button to a tab.

As shown in the image below, the button is appearing at the bottom of the page.

How can I move the radio button to the top of the volcano plot tab?

```
mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(id="foldchanges",type = "tabs",
          tabPanel(title="Summary", value=1, verbatimTextOutput("summary_foldchanges")),
          tabPanel(title="Volcano Plot", value=2, plotOutput("volcanoplot"),

               radioButtons("comparison", label = "Select comparison:",
               choices = list(
                              "option1" = "option1", 
                              "option2"    = "option2", 
                              "option3" = "option3",
                              "option4"      = "option4"),
                               selected = "option2")


                                                   ),
                                          tabPanel("Table normalized",value=3, 
                                           dataTableOutput("tablenormalized"))            

                          )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put the radio button input before the plot :

```
mainPanel(
 tabsetPanel(id="foldchanges",type = "tabs",
          tabPanel(title="Summary", value=1, verbatimTextOutput("summary_foldchanges")),
          tabPanel(title="Volcano Plot", value=2,

                   radioButtons("comparison", label = "Select comparison:",
                                choices = list(
                                  "option1" = "option1", 
                                  "option2"    = "option2", 
                                  "option3" = "option3",
                                  "option4"      = "option4"),
                                selected = "option2"),
                   plotOutput("volcanoplot")


          ),
          tabPanel("Table normalized",value=3, 
                   dataTableOutput("tablenormalized")))))
```

By doing that the radio button will be on top of the volcano plot tab. Is that what you want to  do ?